# getting number of results from google in perl program

Tags: perl, api

Is there an API for google that I can use in my Perl program so that it returns number of results found for a search term?

Whenever a search is done on google, on the far right, it has a number of results it found and the time it took.  I would just like to get this information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CPAN module [Net::Google::Search](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net::Google::Search) implements Google's SOAP API for searching.

Answer (score 7):

Google [deprecated their SOAP API](http://code.google.com/apis/soapsearch/) a couple years ago.  Try using [REST::Google::Search](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?REST::Google::Search) or [Google::Search](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Google::Search), which use their [AJAX API](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/) instead.  I haven't had occasion to try either module myself, so I'm not sure which one is better.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is quite what you're looking for, but you could check to see if it supports your use model: [Google Ajax Search API](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/).

Comment: See my answer for a couple of Perl modules that use that API.